# GPUMp4Composer apply filter

Tags: android, filter

I am creating a video player where after recording a video user should be able to apply gpu filter to the video then upload and then be able to play it.

I applied the GPUMp4Composer library but after applying the filter the video is coming as expected but the audio is getting muted.

```
new GPUMp4Composer(srcMp4Path, destMp4Path)
                .filter(new GlFilterGroup(FilterType.createGlFilter(filterTypes.get(select_postion), getApplicationContext())))
            .listener(new GPUMp4Composer.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(double progress) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            GotopostScreen();
                        }
                    });
                }

                @Override
                public void onCanceled() {
                    Log.d("resp", "onCanceled");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailed(Exception exception) {

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Preview_Video_A.this, "Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            })
            .start();
```

I expect the output video to be with filter and sound but i am getting the filtered video without sound.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same issue, but after updating to latest version, it fixed the audio mute.

```
com.github.MasayukiSuda:GPUVideo-android:v0.1.1
```

Note: Gradle did not gave me hint to update new version, somehow I went to github and found a new version.